# Accessing instance functions from static var

Tags: swift, static

I have been playing with swift challenges at edabit.com

And wanted to run tests in my Xcode playgrounds. So I’ve copied code which looks like this

```
import XCTest

class SolutionTest: XCTestCase {
    static var allTests = [
        ("Test 1", test1),
        ("Test 2", test2),
        ("Test 3", test3)
    ]

    func test1() {
        XCTAssertEqual(addition(2,3), 5)
    }
    func test2() {
        XCTAssertEqual(addition(-3,-6), -9)
    }
    func test3() {
        XCTAssertEqual(addition(7,3), 10)
    }

}

XCTMain([
    testCase(SolutionTest.allTests)
])
```

How they able to store instance functions (test1(), test2() etc) in static allTests variable?

I’ve read here https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/0/18/static-properties-and-methods

> Because static methods belong to the struct itself rather than to instances of that **struct**, you can't use it to access any non-static properties from the struct.

Is it true only for structs?

Also I’ve tried to run all tests from this var array like this

```
SolutionTest.allTests.forEach {(name, func) in
print(name)
func()
}
```

And got error

```
error: missing argument for parameter #1 in call
 test()
     ^
    SolutionTest
```

So I've tried passing instance to function and it worked.

```
SolutionTest.allTests.forEach { (name, func) in
    print(name)
    let sol = SolutionTest()
    func(sol)()
}
```

Why it works this way? What happens under hood?